# Change Mapping for Field for ALL OF LOGSTASH Created indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, logstash, elasticsearch-mapping

I would like to change the type of the field `location` to geo_point. I'm using ES with Logstash, as y'all know, indices are generated with the name `logstash-yyyy-mm-dd`

I first created a logstash index and named it `logstash-2016-03-29`, like so:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016-03-29'
```

then, I changed the mapping for supposedly all the indices called `Logstash-*` using the following:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/_mapping/logs" -d '{
"properties" : {
            "location" : { "type":"geo_point" }
        }
}'
```

And when I ran the Logstash configuration file, all the `location` fields in the index `logstash-2016-03-29` were indeed of type `geo_point`.

However, today, the auto-generated index `logstash-2016-03-30` had field location of type `String` instead of `geo_point`. I thought the type should be applied on ANY index that starts with the name `logstash-*`. Apparently, I was wrong. How can I fix this so that any future index created by logstash that have the `location` field would have that field type set to `geo_point` instead of String?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should define it using the index template

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_2 -d '
{
    "template" : "logstash-",
    "mappings" : {
        "logs" : {
          "properties": {
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html